# Having trouble to get the total price of the basket's items (Django)

Tags: django

So I'm trying to get the total amount of the basket but having trouble doing so.
Am I calling it wrong? I'm new so...

Html(here is the way i calling it):

```
<p>Total:{{basket.get_basket_total}}</p>
```

models:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    products_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    product_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to ='images/', default='images/broken/broken.png')

    def __str__(self):
        if (self.inventory<=0):
            return self.products_name + ' (Out of Stock)'
        return self.products_name

class Basket(models.Model):
    products = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.products)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.products.price * self.amount
        return total

    @property
    def get_basket_total(self):
        basket_items = self.basket_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in basket_items])
        return total
```

View(and it doesnt let me to add this view bec it is mostly code so i am writing this):
View(and it doesnt let me to add this view bec it is mostly code so i am writing this):
View(and it doesnt let me to add this view bec it is mostly code so i am writing this):

```
def products(request):
    products_list = Products.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'products_list': products_list}
    return render(request, 'productapp/products.html', context)

def basket(request):
    basket_list = Basket.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'basket_list': basket_list}
    return render(request, 'productapp/basket.html', context)

def home(request):
    products_list = Products.objects.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = {'products_list': products_list}
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)

def image(request):
    images = Products()
    variables = RequestContext(request,{'product_pic':images})
    return render(None,'image.html',variables)

def addtobasket(request, id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = Products.objects.get(id=id)
        basket, created = Basket.objects.get_or_create(products=product)
        basket.amount=request.POST['amount']
        basket.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("productapp:basket"))

def removefrombasket(request, id):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = Basket.objects.get(id=id)
        product.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("productapp:basket"))
```

Comment: I don't see a method called `get_basket_total()` on your model class. Did you mean `get_total()` or `get_cart_total()`?

Comment: sorry, I have changed it here in html but forgot to change it in the model. the problem is not that.

Comment: What is rendered, a blank area after “Total:”? If so try what is shown if you just use {{basket}}. If still nothing please post the view passing the data to the template

Comment: @Omid, I believe you should do `self.products.basket_set.all()`

Comment: @EdoardoFacchinelli Nothing so I have added the view

Answer (score 0):

You better do:

```
sum(basket.values_list('price', flat=True)
```

So you get all inside the query
With `values_list` you get all the fields of the item in it. `Flat = True` makes it a list.
So you get something like:

```
[15,18,22,31]
```

and you sum it all

Comment: Thanks, but the problem I have I think is that I can't call the function and don't know why or how to do so. it just won't show anything for the {{basket.get_basket_total}}

Comment: I try to understand what you are doing, you are using a foreign key to add many items in the field? The foregn key is used to a single item, you should you manytomany or onetomany field. Then you will get more then 1 item, and then you can get a better total

Comment: So this is a project for a class so I just made one basket for the whole site and you can add the products to the basket. the problem I having is that I want to have the total price of all the added items to the basket using the function get_basket_total. but I can't.

Comment: you can't put more then 1 product at a time into your basket, until you use foreign key field you can add only 1 product at a time. If you want to add more then 1 you have to change the field type

Comment: Each baskets has only one product. And total price of one basket is get_total...

Comment: get all the basket and then add the products in them
    
    def get_basket_total(self):

basket_items = basket.objects.all()
total = sum([item.get_total for item in basket_items])
return total

Comment: can I still do this in Basket function? and I did this and still nothing showing up on site. do you have any idea why it doesn't?

Comment: you can't call a function within a template, you have to call in the view and send the result into the context. So you can try print(RESULT) and see if it working before the template